# Strangeness with Angular validation of input type="number"

Tags: html, angularjs

According to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.number), validation keys for an:
`<input type="number" required />`
are:
   `required` and `number`.

Let's recall that a key's value to `true` means key in error and `false` means fulfilling the expectation.

- If I enter nothing, `required: true` and `number:false`   => why not `number` as `true` since empty string isn't a number?
- If I enter `fergrg`, `required: true` and `number:false`   => why not required to `false` and `number` to `true`?

The only case where it seems logic is when I enter a number, where both `required` and `number` get `false`.

The provided demo in the documentation confirms this rule.

Bug? Or any explanation?

Comment: At a glance, it seems a number input can only ever have a value that is a number. - If you type a string into the demo in the docs, you'll notice the value remains null, so you can't ever have a value which would fail the "number" test.

Comment: @OddEssay Yes, but whatever the mechanism in background is, it really makes no sense to let the `number` key to `false` when letters are entered.

Comment: I do sort of agree, except it's a HTML thing, not an Angular thing. The value of the input type="number" is only ever a valid number, or blank. When you enter a string into the text box, the actual value evaluates to a null string, and it's the actual value that is tested, not the content of the box. Like wise, if you use jQuery to set the value with $(':input[type="number"]').val('moo'); You'll see the input box becomes blank, because the string is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug.
You can check it out in firefox.
the $error of  number should be true.
Visit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/pRc5pu3bWQ0/4yxCdCz1JeMJ